# learning_curve() with holdout set

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

Is there any way to plot the learning curves of training and validation data, when validation data does already exist as a holdout set?
sklearn learning_curve() does not offer such a paramater, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameter `cv` as a `PredefinedSplit` (or just a length-1 iterator of train/test indices).  See the description of `cv` in the documentation.